# OracleClient says my connection is closed

Tags: c#, .net, system.data.oracleclient

I have the following ridiculously simple code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=tnsname;User Id=zzzz;Password=xxxx"))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT * from CONTRACT"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously I've changed the connection string, but if the connection string is wrong, the `conn.Open()` call fails, so I know the connection string is correct, at least as far as the data source, User Id, and Password.

When it gets to the `cmd.ExecuteReader()` call, however, I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the message, `Invalid operation. The connection is closed.`

I've done a lot of SQL Server stuff from C#, but this is the first time I've used OracleClient. Can't see anything obviously wrong, other than the fact that it's deprecated, but I'd figure it would still function. I'm not trying to write any production code, I'm just trying to do a little one-off test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't associated your connection object with command.

```
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

or pass it in Command constructor like:

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT * from CONTRACT", conn))
```

Comment: @Pete no you're no it's a simple oversight your human and we all make mistakes.. at least you have shown credible effort in my opinion.. do get down on yourself for not seeing it right off the bat

Answer (score 1):

You haven't assigned the Connection instance to the OracleCommand instance

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=tnsname;User Id=zzzz;Password=xxxx"))
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT * from CONTRACT", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using(IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                .....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just add the `conn` instance to the constructor of the command.
By the way, also the reader should be enclosed in a using statement

Comment: @Pete the reason that Steve has suggested wrapping the Reader object around a using statement is so that you do not have to explicitly call something like the following to dispose of the object 
`((IDisposible)reader).Dispose();` the using will handle auto disposing for you [C# MSDN using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) check this out in the meantime Pete

Comment: @MethodMan As you can see in my original post, I was already using `using`

Comment: @Pete you are only using it for the outer don't assume that it will handle disposing of the reader but then again only you would know by running some unit test.. thanks